# "Moving" data structure

Tags: arduino

I am doing an Arduino project with a temperature and humidity sensor and trying to combat data inaccuracy. Every 2 seconds I get 2 values: temperature and humidity. I need some sort of data structure with fixed size where I collect values and when the value count reaches structure size, I begin calculating and outputting the average of those values. Once I get more values than the structure can house, the "oldest" value has to be discarded, present values moved down and new data inserted in front.

What sort of data structure should I use considering the fact, that I need this in C/C++?

Comment: _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Comment: ...and `C/C++` is UB...

Comment: A [*circular buffer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) is a suitable data structure.  You can trivially implement that in a `std::vector` or `std::array`: just keep indices to track which elements are currently in use, or alternatively the first in-use element and count thereof.

Comment: Please provide a link to the specification of that C/C++ language you mention. AFAIK this does not exist, but only the two **different** languages C and C++. Note that "Arduino" is actually none of them.

Comment: @Olaf , I did write that I need to solve this in C/C++, where "/" == OR. I did not mention that Arduino is some separate language. AFAIK Arduino IDE supports C/C++, most libraries are C++ classes. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Justin: 1) I did not state **you** mentioned; that does not change the fact. 2) it definitively is not C. 3) Whether it is C++ is questionable at best. It definitively is not pure C++, but uses additional libraries and does not work without them (for a starter: there is no `main` in the application code as required by C++ (and C, btw).

Comment: Just asking, why couldn't a Queue Data Structure can't resolve this problem?
It has fix size. Push the data from top. And when overflow occurs, pop an element from bottom.

Answer (score 1):

A ring buffer would be useful. For more information, you should google for "simple moving average".

Here's another SO question that answers it:
[simple moving average of "live" stream - fast implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338496/simple-moving-average-of-live-stream-fast-implementation)

Comment: I think there might have been a misunderstanding, therefore I'll attempt to explain in another way: let's say you have a pistol magazine which houses 7 bullets. You make a hole in the bottom, so that if you try adding more than 7 bullets, the bottom one falls out to make room for the new one at the top. This magazine also is able to have more than one column which is filled with bullets simultaneously.

Comment: Just commenting to search and linking another answer is no answer by itself.

Comment: @Justin: each circular/ring buffer can handle the kind of use implied by your pistol magazine metaphor - one such buffer equates to one "column".  The insight you seem to be lacking is that it's inefficient to move all the "bullets" downwards every time you insert a new one: with randomly accessible computer memory if's much better - when the "magazine column" is full - to simply overwrite the oldest one with the newest data, but you do need to keep a number or pointer to track where the newest values are overwriting the oldest values.  I suggest you do some reading/experimentation.