# PyAudio distorted recording when while loop too busy

Tags: python, audio, real-time, pyaudio

I have a Python script that monitors an audio stream in real time and uses a moving average to determine when there is audio and set start and stop points based on when it is above or below a given threshold. Because the script runs 24/7, I avoid excessive memory usage by removing part of the audio stream after about 4 hours of audio.

```
def record(Jn):
  global current_levels
  global current_lens
  device_name = j_lookup[Jn]['device']
  device_index = get_index_by_name(device_name)
  audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
  stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, input_device_index=device_index, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

  recorded_frames = []
  quantized_history = []
  long_window = int(LONG_MOV_AVG_SECS*RATE/CHUNK) # converting seconds to while loop counter

  avg_counter_to_activate_long_threshold = LONG_THRESH*long_window
  safety_window = 1.5*avg_counter_to_activate_long_threshold
  long_thresh_met = 0

  long_start_selection = 0
  while True:
    data = stream.read(CHUNK, exception_on_overflow=False)
    recorded_frames.append(data)
    frame_data = struct.unpack(str(CHUNK) + 'h', data)
    frame_data = np.array(frame_data)
    sum_abs_frame = np.sum(np.abs(frame_data))
    quantized_history.append(0 if sum_abs_frame < j_lookup[Jn]['NOISE_FLOOR'] else 1)
    current_levels[Jn] = sum_abs_frame

    counter = len(recorded_frames)
    current_lens[Jn] = counter
    if counter >= long_window:
      long_movavg = sum(quantized_history[counter-long_window:counter])/long_window
      if long_movavg >= LONG_THRESH and long_thresh_met != 1:
        long_start_selection = int(max(counter - safety_window, 0))
        long_thresh_met = 1
      if long_movavg < LONG_THRESH and long_thresh_met == 1:
        long_end = int(counter)
        long_thresh_met = 2
        save_to_disk(recorded_frames[long_start_selection:long_end], audio, Jn)

    if counter > MAX_LOOKBACK_PERIOD: # don't keep endless audio history to avoid excessive memory usage
      del recorded_frames[0]
      del quantized_history[0]
      long_start_selection = max(0, long_start_selection - 1) # since you deleted first element, the recording start index is now one less
```

What I have above works, but what I noticed is that once I hit the four hour mark (the `if counter > MAX_LOOKBACK_PERIOD` statement at the very end becomes true), any audio saved after that point starts to sound distorted. For example, before the four hour point, the audio looks like:

[image]

after the four hour mark, it looks like:

[image]

You can see the distortion appearing as these vertical spikes on the spectrogram. I assume the `del` function is just taking so long that the while loop can't keep up with the audio stream and this is somehow causing the distortion, but I'm not sure. It has to be related to `del` somehow because the distortion only appears once the `if counter > MAX_LOOKBACK_PERIOD` becomes true.

Any idea how to address this?

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the `del` being problematic. The issue is that popping the first element of a `list` of length N has a complexity of O(N).

You might want to try using a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) from the built-in `collections` instead. `deque` is optimized for access at either end, making `append`- and `pop`-type operations quicker (complexity of O(1)), especially if you have a larger array.

Additionally, you can specify the maximum length you want for your `deque`, which would make the popping automatic.

***Edit*** :
To illustrate this, a small toy example/benchmark:

```py
import timeit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

maxlens, tls, tqs = [], [], []
deque_test_code = """
my_queue.append(1)
"""
list_test_code = """
del my_list[0]
my_list.append(1)
"""


for i in range(10):

    MAX_LEN = 2**(4+i)
    maxlens.append(MAX_LEN)

    print(20*"-")
    print(f"{MAX_LEN=}")

    setup = f"""
from collections import deque
my_list = {MAX_LEN}*[0]
my_queue = deque(my_list, maxlen={MAX_LEN})
"""

    tl = timeit.timeit(
        setup=setup,
        stmt=list_test_code,
    )
    tls.append(tl)

    tq = timeit.timeit(
        setup=setup,
        stmt=deque_test_code,
    )
    tqs.append(tq)


plt.plot(maxlens, tls, 'x-', label="list time")
plt.plot(maxlens, tqs, 'x-', label="deque time")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The results on my machine :

[image: deque vs list timeit plot]

Comment: my concern with the deque is that i need to be able to slice it to get the moving average; i'm not sure if that will be slower with a deque than a list. I also have to do a slice to save the audio data, but that doesn't happen every iteration of the loop so I'm less worried there.

Comment: true - in that case, I might suggest looking into a faster "streaming" moving average algorithm to avoid having to slice the list/deque. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24707882/21688300) suggests a few possibilities: "simple moving average" (which coincidentally is also a great use case for another `deque` XD ) or an "exponential moving average" (which is trivially simple to implement).

Comment: I created an implementation using a deque and, as soon as the maxlen is hit, I start getting the audio corruption again. Is it possible that the constant time it takes the deque to remove an old element while adding a new one is so slow it is comparable to the O(n) time of deleting the first element in the list implementation? I haven't run any benchmarks yet to test but that's my only guess at this point.

Comment: probably not, unless your N is really tiny? On a toy example on my machine, I find that `deque` is always slightly faster than `list`, however it really starts to become noticable at N>1000.  Of course, this could be totally different on another machine. I'll add my code to the answer, for reference.